# Is it possible to make a pseudo isometric game with phaser?

Tags: phaser

If I use the [isometric plugin](http://rotates.org/phaser/iso/) for Phaser, I end up with something like the third case of the following picture:

[image]

I would like to create a world in pseudo isometric, with only one axis tilted. This would be the second case in the picture.

Is it possible to achieve that with Phaser? With or without the Isometric plugin? If Phaser can't handle it, is there an open-source/free alternative for this kind of setup?

Comment: I never worked with Phaser, but any engine handling the first case should handle the second just fine if it is able to determine the draw order of sprites by the y-coordinate and supports sprites of arbitrary size.

Comment: The style you're looking for is a parallel projection commonly called a "3/4 View" (examples from [GD.SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/17623/rendering-tiles-on-3-4-perspective), [TV Tropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ThreeQuartersView)) - you may get better hits for this term than "pseudo-isometric," since even [as sloppy as we are with the term "isometric" in games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_graphics_in_video_games_and_pixel_art), we usually apply it only to views that show three sides rather than two.

Answer (score 3):

Phaser handles this out of the box using sorting based on the y index. I have used this exact technique too to create stacked sprites so the elements at the bottom of the screen are drawn over the ones above.

https://phaser.io/examples/v2/groups/depth-sort

The trick used in Phaser is to sort the z index based on the y index so the characters sprite is drawn at the correct depth.